# How to perform difference on partitioned column over order by clause?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Consider a table like the following:

```
col1  col2  col3

1000  RRR   100000
2000  RRR   400000
3000  RRR   300000
4000  YYY   200000
5000  YYY   400000
6000  RRR   400000
6000  ZZZ   500000
```

The output I want:

```
1000  RRR  0
2000  RRR  300000
3000  RRR  100000
6000  RRR  400000
....
```

I need to perform partition on `col2`, order by on `col3` and then find difference on rows.

Comment: Hello Bijendra, nice to see you in StackOverflow. Please try to be more descriptive with your problem, provide us with some insights of what are you trying to achieve. Provide us with a working using a plunkr or similar, or at least a piece of code that is usable to reproduce your error. 
Don't forget to format your question using de `  for code  `<h1> Like this </h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet as a base for your query:

```
SELECT c1, c2,
       c3 - nvl(lag(c3) OVER (PARTITION BY c2 ORDER BY c1), c3) as diff
FROM t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.. what you meant by nv1 ??

Comment: NVL is a hive function to deal with nulls, in case is there is no previous value http://www.hplsql.org/nvl

Comment: Yeah Thanks!! Above query didn't serve my result, as my requirement is 1st row of every partition should have same value. Like in R1 C3 value should be same base table. But after using lag value is getting deducted by 1 and respectively in every partition value is getting deducted as offset value....please help..

Comment: Can you produce an example what is wrong and how you want to correct it?

Comment: Hello, here is the sample example. sample table 1,England,10000
2,newyork,20000
3,England,30000
4,Wales,40000
5,England,50000
6,newyork,60000
7,England,70000
8,wales,80000. when i have run the suggested query i got the following result: 1 England 9999
3 England 20000
5 England 20000
7 England 20000
4 Wales 39996
2 newyork 19998
6 newyork 40000
8 wales 79992
Expected Result: 1 England 10000
3 England 20000
4 England 20000
7 England 20000
2 newyork 20000
6 newyork 40000
4 wales   40000
8 wales   40000.

Comment: if you will notice as my requirement is not to change the 1st row c3 value but 2nd row should have c3(row1-row2) ordered by and 
so on every partition as i am doing patition by on c2....